# How many endings are there and what will it take to see them all?

Tags: mass-effect-3

With all the possible permutations between choices in ME3 and in previous ME games, how many different endings are there in the game and what is the most effective playthrough method to see all the endings?

Comment: Just from ME3? or the entire series?

Comment: @Foxtrot I'm interested in the entire series

Comment: How is this different from my post that got a ton of downvotes?
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53745/total-possible-outcomes-in-the-mass-effect-trilogy

Comment: @foxtrot I think the only difference between yours and mine is I'm simply looking for the major endings rather than all the little outcomes of every action you take in the entire series.  Yours is more of a superset of mine, but I don't see why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Outcomes(Spoilers)

> Collector’s Base Saved in ME2
>
> - Readiness Rating < 1750 – Earth is destroyed regardless of whatever decisions you made.
> - Readiness Rating 1750 – Choose to Save the Reapers and the Earth will be saved.
> - Readiness Rating 2050 – Choose to become a Reaper and the Earth will be saved.
> - Readiness Rating 2350 – Choose to destroy the Reapers and Earth is destroyed.
> - Readiness Rating 2650 – Choose to destroy the Repears and the Earth will be somewhat destroyed
> - Readiness Rating 2800 – Earth and the Galaxy will be saved once you’re able to create synergy
> - Readiness Rating 4000 – Choose to destroy the Reapers and Save Anderson to see Shepard alive.
> - Readiness Rating 5000 – Choose to destroy the reapers and fail to Save Anderson to see Shepard alive.
>
> Collector’s Base Destroyed in ME2
>
> - Readiness Rating < 1750 – Earth is destroyed regardless of whatever decisions you made.
> - Readiness Rating 1750 – Choose to become a Reaper and the Earth will be destroyed.
> - Readiness Rating 1900 – Choose to destroy the Repears and the Earth will be somewhat -destroyed
> - Readiness Rating 2350 – Choose to become a Reaper and the Earth will be saved.
> - Readiness Rating 2650 – Choose to destroy the Reapers and Earth will be saved.
> - Readiness Rating 2800 – Earth and the Galaxy will be saved once you’re able to create synergy
> - Readiness Rating 4000 – Choose to destroy the Reapers and Save Anderson to see Shepard alive.
> - Readiness Rating 5000 – Choose to destroy the reapers and fail to save Anderson to see Shepard alive.

There are numerous ways to increase readiness and depending on your import save status, single player decisions, multiplayer skill, and multiplayer time, the "most efficient" way to manipulate readiness doesn't really have a universal answer for players.

Comment: -1, there seems to be a lack of explanation for the "how to see them all most efficiently"...

Comment: I'm learning formatting, please hold while I spoiler protect while also keeping friendly format

Comment: is that right? a lower readiness rating (2350) for saving the collector base will result in earth only somewhat being destroyed but a higher one (2650 also saving the base) will result in the earth being completely destroyed?

Comment: It was mentioned in ME2 about the collector base containing technology that could possibly help in fighting the reapers. Destroying it was a call you had to make.

Comment: Not sure if it really needed a downvote :/

Comment: These are all speculations. At this moment, only 3 endings are confirmed.

Comment: The source for this is the official Prima guide. It's not speculation.

Comment: Bioware mentions 16 permutations of the ending, the guide is correct, and great job!

Comment: Worth noting that the Prima Guide contains errors elsewhere, such as saying Kaidan is only available as a romance option for female Shepards, and it does mention the "secret ending" no one has been able to verify, so we should perhaps take the guide's advice with a grain of salt.
All that being said, the guide says that if you did not destroy the Collector's base, at 2350 Earth is "devastated but still there," not that it's destroyed.