# Mass Effect 3 Ending

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many endings are there and what will it take to see them all?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53964/how-many-endings-are-there-and-what-will-it-take-to-see-them-all)

> I finished ME3 and I choose the option to destroy the reapers.
> As some of you may know both endings show the Normandy crashed and Joker and the others come out.
> But my ending was like a mix of them both. When the Normandy door opened the credits started. They didn't show Joker! After the credits they showed the conversation betweeen the child and the stargazer. Is it because of the actions I made in the game?

- I choose the Renegade path
- I had under 5000 war power

Do these factors change the ending?

Comment: by under 5k war power, what was the number?  I have seen reports that this is referred to as the "worst" ending.

Answer (score 2):

The major factor to what your ending is, are the War assets.  That determines which of the several choices you get to have, according to [**this**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53967/12823) answer.

I'll assume this is the ending you got:

Assuming the title is correct, this is the *worst* possible ending, where there are no survivors because the Crucible not only killed the Reapers, but everything else too (including Joker =[)

Being a Renegade does not fully affect which options you have, but in this case the *Renegade* option is considered to be Destroying the Reapers (signified by the Red of the beam) just like how saving the collector base was considered the *Renegade* option, signified by the colour of the star behind the Illusive Man in ME2

Comment: Oh dear,yeah I had the worst one.But why does the door open?I am assuming that someone is still alive in the Normandy

Comment: Might be a plot hole, might just be a malfunction, we might never know.