# What is the minimum war assets value do you need to have to get the best ending?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many endings are there and what will it take to see them all?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53964/how-many-endings-are-there-and-what-will-it-take-to-see-them-all)

Just the number or a approximation and without playing multilayer (50% readiness).

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53964/how-many-endings-are-there-and-what-will-it-take-to-see-them-all  Is it even possible to get 8000 war assets (with 50% readiness)???

Comment: It may be a duplicate, but the other question is plagued with spoilers i just wanted the number.