# Does war assets really affect the ending of Mass effect 3

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many endings are there and what will it take to see them all?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53964/how-many-endings-are-there-and-what-will-it-take-to-see-them-all)

Does having very little war assets really affect the ending of Mass effect 3